# Transfering new drive from Windows to Linux

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs, gpt

I recently got a new 3TB hard drive which I plan on loading up with video files on my Window PC and then transfering the hard drive to my Linux PC/server.

I formatted the drive as NTFS (since I was told that NTFS is compatible in both environments) and partitioned the drive as GPT (since I read this was also compatible in both environments), but, even though it detects the drive on my Linux PC, I'm getting an error when trying to access it which reads:

```
Error mounting /dev/sdb2 at media/me/LONGSTRINGOFNUMBERSANDCHARACTERSTHATIBELIEVEISHEXID‌​ECIMALCODE:
Command-line 'mount-t "ntfs" -o "unhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sdb2" "media/me/SAMELONGSTRINGASABOVE"' exited with non-zero exit status 14:
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount. 
Failed to mount '/dev/sdb2': Operation not permitted. The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

Anybody have any idea what this means? What I have to do to fix this??

Comment: Using `ntfsfix` might be enough.

Comment: @muru is that a linux terminal command?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/532753/158442, https://askubuntu.com/a/499541/158442

Comment: @muru the issue was that i actually had 'quick start' enabled on windows which doesn't shut the computer down entirely but rather puts the PC into a quasi-hibernation state. i guess that's actually the same issue. thanks for the linux solution to the problem!! <3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you shut windows down with QuickStart enabled?? 
Win8.1 and later doesn't really shut down, it hibernates.

Plug the drive back into a windows system. scan it with windows to be sure it is ok, then eject the drive while windows s running.

It should then be readable by ubuntu.

Comment: No I didn't. I fully shutdown Windows before d/cing the drive. I will try again, though, later tonight. Ubuntu detects the drive, but I just can't access it :/

Comment: @Anthony -- windoows does not fully shut down unless quick start is disabled. defaut is a quazy hibernate. not a full shutdown.  Eject the drive to remove it.

Comment: Wow. Thanks!! I actually did have it enabled. I thought I disabled that a while ago. Hopefully that works. I'll be testing this later tonight and i'll let you know!!

Comment: @Anthony -- windows updates will likely re-enable it. Recheck after applying updates.

Comment: you were right!! that was exactly the problem. damn that kind of had me worried there for a second. thanks so much for your help <33